# Why cant my win 8.1 laptop to find *my* WLAN

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a cheap win 8.1 Packard Bell laptop.

I have a WLAN that is detectable by win7, OSX, iPad, 2*iPhone another win 8.1 laptop and a Samsung phone.

But I cant get the PB-laptop to find *my* WLAN. It finds about 8 of my neighbors WLANS though.

I have had no luck entering the WLAN name manually.

Any advise on how to proceed to fix this?

Comment: Perhaps your access point is set to only broadcast a minimum wifi standard such a "N", which all of your other devices support; but your laptop only supports "G"?

Comment: as I know N is backwards compatible with G...

Answer (score 0):

There are different standarts of wireless connection such as 802.11 a,b,g,n (these four are widespread).
Your WiFi adapter doesn't support your access point's connection type.
Look at your adapter specifications and AP specifications to check it.

802.11A and B are the lowest versions.
802.11G is backwards compatible with B,
802.11N is backwards compatible with A/B/G,
802.11AC is backwards compatible with A/B/G/N.
(Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) article from Wikipedia for more info).

For example, if your laptop adapter is 802.11a, it will not be compatible with 802.11g access point (AP).